# How to Print whole array inside square brackets rather then printing every single value?

Tags: c++, arrays

In the following code I want to print the whole array instead of printing each single value. Can we do that? I'm familiar with python where we append values but I can't find that in C++. So how to get desired result. What if I have to print it using printf?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int *name(){
static int n[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    n[i]=i;}
return n;}

int main(){
    int *p;
    p=name();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<*(p+i)<<endl;}
return 0;
```

desired output should be -

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Start with `cout << '[';`

Comment: If I add cout << '['; it will print [ everytime

Comment: Is that not what you want?

Comment: I want to put square brackets around the whole array not around each value

Comment: @jerry You have to add everything that you want outputted 'manually'. There are almost no 'pretty printer' functions already built-in in C++.

Comment: Put the `cout << '['` before the start of the loop

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *name() {
    static int n[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        n[i] = i;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int *p;
    p = name();
    cout << '[';
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        cout << *(p+i) << (i != 4 ? ',' : ']');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to encapsulate the array-printing into a general function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

std::string PrintArray(int* array, size_t size) {
    std::string answer = "[";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        answer += std::to_string(array[i]);
        answer += (i < size-1) ? "," : "]";
    }
    return answer;
}

int* name() {
    static int n[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        n[i] = i;
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {
    int* p;
    p = name();
    cout << PrintArray(p, 5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually end up overloading `operator<<` for the desired type, but your mileage may vary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class InputIt>
std::ostream& print_impl(std::ostream& os, InputIt first, InputIt last)
{
    os << '[';
    if (first != last)
    {
        os << *first;
        while ( ++first != last )
            os << ", " << *first;
    }
    return os << ']';
}

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    return print_impl(os, v.cbegin(), v.cend());
}

template <class T, size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const (&a)[N])
{
    return print_impl(os, std::cbegin(a), std::cend(a));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};   
    std::cout << a << '\n';

    float b[] = {3.14f, -0.1f, 2.0f};
    std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```